# Can't stop percona xtradb cluster node

Tags: mysql, replication, percona

I have three Percona xtradb nodes running on ubuntu 12.04 computers.  I want to stop one of the nodes, without disconnecting eth0.

I have tried: `$ service mysql stop` and `$ /etc/init.d/mysql stop`

Both commands say `stopping...OK`.  But I can still connect to mysql on the node.

How can I take a node out of the cluster temporarily?

Comment: This is most likely a PID file path issue. Check to make sure you are specifying the PID file in /etc/my.cnf and also check that the init scripts have the right value as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem on my Ubuntu 12.04 server, too.

The only thing I could find to kill "mysqld" was this command:

```
sudo stop mysql
```

Pretty simple, I know. But it worked for me. Hopefully this will sort you out too.

Source: http://www.itfromscratch.com/how-to-stop-the-percona-mysql-server/

Comment: or sudo service mysql stop

Answer (score 0):

You can always cleanly shut down any MySQL server using "mysqladmin shutdown" (provided you have the proper privileges/credentials)